# How to code auto set date and time in php

Tags: php

Attribute `DateAdded` is example of auto set date and time, Any one can show me how to do auto set date and time. What I want is if I submit new insert form in my system, date and time will be show in the database.

**example data in database**

```
DateAdded = 2011-07-28 11:17:09
```

Comment: You mean the attributes are in the MySQL table??

Comment: for php current date see this link http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
$DateAdded = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
```

Answer (score 0):

**MySQL solutions**

Use `timestamp`, While you creating DateAdded coulmn

or

Use `Now()` in insert Query

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
  $dateAdded = date( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' );
```

or your database function to get the current time function, like '`NOW()`' or '`SYSDATE()`'.

Answer (score 0):

You can set that in the column property itself. On creating the table just add the property `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`, and then whenever the a row is inserted, the time will be updated automatically. For further details check the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/timestamp.html)